# My Web Api action return all data instead of one

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, lazy-loading

One way to fix this problem is to turn lazy loading off ..... if i do not want to turn off lazy loading, is there other solution?

my action is look like this

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AspNetUsers))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{

    var user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName == id);
    if (user == null)
        return null; //":کاربر نامعتبر";
    JsonResult js = new JsonResult();
    js.Data = user;
    js.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    js.ContentType = "Application/json";
    js.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    //var returnUser = user.UserName + user.Email + user.FirstName + user.LastName +
    //                 user.AspNetRoles.Select(s => s.Name);
    return Ok(js);/// or return ok(user)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing MVC and Web Api concepts and object.

`JsonResult` is an MVC derived `ActionResult` object while `IHttpActionResult` is associated with Web API.

Also, if you don't want to return all the data then don't. Construct a new object result model and return only what is needed.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(UserModel))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id) {

    var user = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName == id);
    if (user == null)
        return NotFound();

    var data = new UserModel {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Roles = user.AspNetRoles.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()
        //...other properties you want to return
    };       
    return Ok(data);
}

public class UserModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix my Problem whit little change in Nkosi answer .....

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(UserModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {

        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Include(a=>a.AspNetRoles).Where(s => s.UserName == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound();

        var data = new UserModel
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Email = user.Email,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Roles = user.AspNetRoles.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray()
            //...other properties you want to return
        };
        return Ok(data);
    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

thanks alot

Comment: This looks like a copy paste of Nkosi answer. Better if you delete this answer and mark Nkosi answer as the Answer (using the checkbox next to the answer). This will show others that this was correct and it will also award Nkosi points for helping you.